# update xml file dynamically at runtime

Tags: java, xml

How can we edit xml file dynamically at runtime using java program. for eg, I have xml file like this,

```
<chart>
<set label="Item A" value="4"/>
<set label="Item B" value="5"/>
<set label="Item C" ``alue="6"/>
<set label="Item D" value="7"/>
</chart>
```

I have tried jdom API for update xml at runtime. But it can edit only single value tags. But here i have multitags with same name. I want to change the value dynamically for every  tags at runtime. Can any one suggest me any ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using jdom-1.1.2.jar

```
Document doc = (Document) builder.build(YourFileName);
Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
List<Element> childrenNode = rootNode.getChildren();
      for (Element child : childrenNode) {
           System.out.println(child.getAttribute("value").getIntValue());
           child.getAttribute("value").setValue("2");
      }

// print updates to xml file with good formatting
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(YourFileName));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer friend. I done this task using dom4j API. anyhow thanks a lot for your answer..